# Segmentation fault in skype.Attach() in Python and Skype4Py

Tags: linux, python-2.7, skype4py

I tried to run a simple python code for Skype4Py here's my code

```
import Skype4Py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
print 'OK'
# Create Skype instance
print 'CREATE'
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
print 'CREATED'

# Connect Skype object to Skype client
print 'CONNECT'
skype.Attach()
print 'CONNECTED'

print 'Your full name:', skype.CurrentUser.FullName
print 'Your contacts:'
for user in skype.Friends:
  print 'LOOP'
  print '    ', user.FullName
  print 'DONE'
```

and my output is this

```
OK
CREATE
INFO:Skype4Py.skype.Skype:object created
INFO:Skype4Py.api.posix_dbus.SkypeAPI:opened
CREATED
CONNECT
INFO:Skype4Py.api.posix_dbus.SkypeAPI:thread started
Segmentation fault
Segmentation in skype.Attach().
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I see no error on Ubuntu 12.04 (it prints correct info). I've installed it as: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-skype`

Comment: i tried to test that in ubuntu but the result is still the same

Comment: You could get stacktrace using faulthandler module or gdb. What is your software versions e.g., `dpkg -l python-skype`  or `apt-cache show python-skype` mine: `1.0.31.0-2~precise1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use X11 transport to avoid segmentation faults

https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot/blob/master/sevabot/bot.py#L30

Also use patched version of Skype4Py and do not try to use anything provided by your Linux distribution

https://github.com/stigkj/Skype4Py

More information about the segfaults with Skype4Py

https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot#segfaults

Comment: i tried this and i don't get any seg fault every time I run my program. Thanks a lot Mikko :)